# Styling Qml desktop components

Tags: c++, css, qt, qml

Currently I'm working on a desktop application that supports touchscreen display. I use QML on Qt 4.8 and OpenSUSE 13.1 (I can't upgrade either Qt or the OS due to dependencies reason)

Because of the lack of main components, I use [qml desktop component](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-components/desktop/source/b96e92a936b3fba8622bc721861ec7cbfd3fdb02:). However, I don't find a way to style those conveniently, like use CSS. Something like change the color of the button, change the border... seem complicated

I've read [Qml styling guide](https://qt-project.org/wiki/QmlStyling), [Qml integrating guide](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-integration.html) but can't find a satisfied answer.

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: It is difficult to answer if we don't know exactly what you want to do. "Style a component" is too vague.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it kinda like the effect of CSS on GUI components like `QLineEdit, QPushButton...`

Answer (score 0):

sry for my english, 
  You could make specific qml object for each type, like this

> TimesItalic.qml

```
Text{
     FontLoader {
         id:timesNewRomanItalic;
         source:"qrc:/Assets/Fonts/times_italic"
         onStatusChanged: console.log("Font loaded " + name)
     }

     font.family: timesNewRomanItalic.name
     color : "#FFFFFF"
 }
```

and call this qml object each time you need it

```
TimesItalic{
    id:myText
    anchors.fill:parent
    text: "Times new roman italic"
}
```

(this example is not optimised)